# How to find the recently modified row in tables of a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL database (`employee`) consists of 5 tables. How to find the recently modified row by column name `id` in tables?

I tried to find the table using the coding below. It works fine.

```
USE
    information_schema;
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM TABLES
WHERE
    UPDATE_TIME IS NOT NULL AND UPDATE_TIME < NOW() AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'employee'
```

Please help to find the row by column name `id` (all tables have this column name as identifier) in that table.

Comment: MySQL does not store this information on its own. If you need this for the future, maybe add an [`on update current_timestamp`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html)-column to each table. If you need it retrospectively, you might find something in the logs (e.g. maybe you have enabled binary logs) or by comparing it to a recent backup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the work around for this problem is to create a trigger that will insert a record into a different table

```
CREATE TABLE `table_row_monitor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tbl` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `val` int,
  `dtecreated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`process_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS chk_pickup_contact_for_delivery;
   DELIMITER $$

   CREATE TRIGGER `[table_name]_log_row_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `[table_name]` FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN

     INSERT INTO table_row_monitor (tbl, col, val)
     SELECT '[table_name]', 'id', MAX(id) FROM `[table_name]`;

   END$$
   DELIMITER ;
```

just replace the [table_name]